# In JPA, is EntityManager.refresh() useful with a disabled cache

Tags: java, caching, jpa

Got some newbie question. In JPA, if the cache is disabled, is it always true that a call to `EntityManager.refresh()` no longer has any use?

I am maintaining this app wherein the cache was disabled but it still calls refresh. I'm thinking to remove the refresh call as I think it's not needed and unnecessarily adds up to the processing, but as it is not my original code so have some doubt if there is any impact.

Appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 4):

One thing you should be aware of is that there are multiple layers of cache involved (you are referring to the second level cache, I suppose). An entity manager is also a first level cache - the scope of which is either bound to the transaction or the lifetime of the extended persistence context.

The `refresh()` method is used to update an existing and managed (part of the persistence context of the current EM) entity with changes made to the db by other entity managers.  So whether or not a second level cache is present or not does have nothing to do with sense and nonsense of refresh() calls.